# Image height not matching with table height

Tags: html, css

I put an image of height 900px inside a table also of height 900px. But for some reason an added 5px height automatically gets added to the bottom of the table. Here is the code. Could someone explain why this is happening? Thanks.

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
   <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="650" height="900" style="border-collapse: collapse;" style="border-top: 1px solid white;">
        <tr>
         <td><img src="dummy.png" alt="#" style="width: 296px; height:auto;"></td>
        </tr>
   </table>
</body>
```

Comment: for me , the image is in the middle of table cell. is that the problem?

Comment: The image is aligned with the text baseline? Try adding `vertical-align: bottom` to the image.

Comment: I don't think that should be a problem. If you put an actual image of that dimension, it sould expand out and fill the table. @MohitBhasi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An image is an inline element by default. Add the following style to your image and the white space will disappear.

```
img{display:block}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/83oheyhL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

It's a known problem of tables and td

Set the image as background of the td

http://jsfiddle.net/F6Gds/30/

```
<body>
<table align="center" border="1" width="296" height="900">
<tr>
<td style="background-image:url(http://dummyimage.com/296x900/ccc/fff);">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: I downvoted your answer because the white space on the bottom is not related to tables or tds. You will see the whitespace also in a div for example. The white space on the bottom is due to the fact that an image is an inline element by default.

Comment: Well, I saw a lot of people with the same problem using tables, I was just trying to give a possible solution, which is it, no need to bury the newcomer, as your answer was already accepted.